# How to return current rotation of Aframe entity

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

This code worked for me once but does no longer. I am trying to figure out how to rotate an entity the wraps a few elements in a scene.

```
 var entityEl = document.querySelector('#rotate');
    console.log(entityEl.components);//returns components object
    var entityRotY = entityEl.components.rotation.attrValue.y;//rotation is undefined

    function rotate(){
        entityEl.setAttribute('rotation', {x: 0, y: entityRotX + 1, z: 0});
        entityRotY++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your method [seems to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/ou7r9hou), I'm not sure if messing with the `attrValue` is a proper way.

Instead try `getAttribute('rotation')` or `entityEl.object3D.rotation` (radian output!)